# Limit Using Any Char at max one time Using Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

**What is My Problem**

I'm trying to limit using for example letter a to one in time in all input text.

```
this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
```

its working perfect and limit dot '.' Char one time.
but if we need to limit other char for exampl

```
this.value.replace(/[^a-z.]/g, '').replace(/(aa*)a/g, '$1');
```

tring to limit letter 'a' **not working**.
***just limit if typing letter in same position, i mean if i write `a` and `a` it replace that but `a` and `any thing` and `a` not working***

### in short way:

I Need Like This

> '<kbd>**a**</kbd><kbd>**a**</kbd>564'  **=>**  '<kbd>**a**</kbd>123ngh564'
>
> '<kbd>**a**</kbd>123ngh<kbd>**a**</kbd>564'  **=>**  '<kbd>**a**</kbd>123ngh564'

### thanks

### Finaly

**Big Thanks For @WiktorStribiżew**
for The solution in the comments.

```js
  s.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '').replace(/(a.*)a/gi, '$1');
```

Comment: Use `s.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '').replace(/(a.*)a/gi, '$1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **thank** you, it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your exact scenario and setup, the following solution will work:

```
s.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '').replace(/(a.*)a/gi, '$1')
```

It will remove all chars other than ASCII letters and digits and `.` (with `.replace(/[^a-z0-9.]/gi, '')`) and then it will remove an `a` that follows an `a` and any 0+ chars other than line break chars (with `.replace(/(a.*)a/gi, '$1')`).

Moreover, in your case, the `g` modifier in `.replace(/(a.*)a/gi` seems redundant, as you are likely to modify the string while the user is typing it (so there will always be only 1 or 2 `a`s).